# Setting Locale independeant of language for web application ( JSF )

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, locale, multilingual, setlocale

i m giving user ability to choose locale (say en_US and en_UK) .
and i want to see date and amount fields with respect to locale foe whole application.
no hard (coded strings).

can u please tell me how to do that . how to set locale for user in facescontext of JSF web application.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373153/how-to-set-the-locale-programmatically-in-jsf?lq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388426/jsf-2-0-set-locale-throughout-session-from-browser-and-programmatically?rq=1, or really, a google search

Comment: i all ready tried those solutions but didn't work..

Comment: i bulit locale using localebuilder (java) and then assigned to application .. it finally worked