# JSF resets locale

Tags: java, jsf-2, internationalization, locale

This code is totally simplified, but reproduces my problem:

### BackingBean.java

```
public String reload(){
    System.out.println(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getViewRoot().getLocale());
    return "test";
}

public void setLocale(){
    System.out.println("locale changed!");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getViewRoot().setLocale(Locale.FRANCE);
}
```

### test.xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink action="#{backingBean.reload}" value="reload page"/>
</h:form>
<h:form>
   <h:commandLink action="#{backingBean.setLocale}" value="change locale"/>
</h:form>
```

### output:

```
en
locale changed!
fr_FR
en
```

---

If you'll change locale and then call `reload` method twice, locale resets to default `en`. What the reason of `locale` reset? Also, it happens only in case of forwarding to other page, if you'll change `reload` method to `void`, locale will be `fr` still.

```
public void reload(){
    System.out.println(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getViewRoot().getLocale());
}
```

### output:

```
en
locale changed!
fr_FR
fr_FR
```

But after 2 forwards locale will be changed back to `en`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The view locale is not remembered in the session scope. It's remembered in the view scope (heck, the view itself represents the whole view scope!).

If you need to remember the locale in the session scope, then you need to create a session scoped managed bean and reference it as a property in `<f:view locale>` of master template.

```html
<f:view locale="#{localeManager.locale}">
```

#### See also:

- [JSF 2.0 set locale throughout session from browser and programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388426/jsf-2-0-set-locale-throughout-session-from-browser-and-programmatically/5391493#5391493)